# If $f$ is differentiable at $4$ and $f^\prime(4) = 5$, evaluate the following limit: $\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{f(x)-f(4)}{\sqrt{x} - 2}$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

If $f$ is differentiable at $4$ and $f^\prime(4) = 5$, evaluate the following limit: $\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{f(x)-f(4)}{\sqrt{x} - 2}$.

\begin{align*}
\\ h &= \sqrt{x} - 2
\\
\\ h \to 0 &\text{ as } x \to 4
\\
\\ \lim_{x \to 4} \frac{f(x)-f(4)}{\sqrt{x} - 2} &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(4)}{h}
\\ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(4-h)-f(x)}{-h} &\implies \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(4-h)-f(4)}{-h} = f^\prime(4) = 5
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{f(x)-f(4)}{\sqrt{x} - 2}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{f(x)-f(4)}{x-4}(\sqrt x+2)$$

$$=f'(4)\cdot\lim_{x \to 4}(\sqrt x+2)=\cdots$$

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{f(x)-f(4)}{x-4} = f^\prime(4)$ because the bottom goes to $0$ as $x \to 4$ correct?

Comment: @Alex, $$f'(x)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$  Set $x=4,h=4-x$

Comment: that's what I stated in my first solution attempt I believe, what was I missing though?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this. $$f(4 + h) = f(4) + 5h+\cdots, \sqrt{4+h} = (4+h)^{1/2} = 4^{1/2} + \frac12 4^{-1/2}h+\cdots \\\to f(4+h) - f(4) = 5h+\cdots, \sqrt{4+h} = 2 +\frac 14 h+\cdots  \\
\to \frac{f(4+h) - f(4)}{\sqrt{4+h} - 2 }= 20+\cdots$$ so the limit is $20.$